# Move files from all pending (shelved) changelists to a new changelist

Tags: perforce, shelve, changelist

In perforce, I have several shelved changelists. I want to move the files from all of these shelved changelists to a new changelist.

I can do this with `p4 reopen -c [new changelist no.] [file 1, file 2, etc]`, but it's laborious to copy and paste the names of each opened file from the previous changelists.

Is there a faster / better way to do this?

Comment: Are the files already open in the shelved changelist, or do you want to move the shelved files?

Comment: They're already open in the shelved changelists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to move the shelved files, you can use the [unshelve](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_unshelve.html) command to do this. You could run `p4 unshelve -s <shelved changelist> -c <target changelist>` for each shelved changelist.

If the files are already open in the shelved changelist, I'm pretty sure you'd need to revert them first.